# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu Link Won't Align with Rest of Links in Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, navbar

For some reason dropdown links do not align with the rest of the links in the Bootstrap navbar and are positioned lower.  I can also see when using a the live preview that it is positioned strangely within its boundaries which you can see in my screen shot. The blue outline represents ".dropdown"

[image]

I found someone having the exact same problem here:

[How to align dropdown menu in Navbar in Bootstrap with css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196301/how-to-align-dropdown-menu-in-navbar-in-bootstrap-with-css)

However, that solution is not working for me. In fact I cannot change the position of the drop down link at all with positioning, margins or padding.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button id="menuButton" type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span><br>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span><br>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
         <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/rainbowLogo.png" id="homeLogo"></a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="navbar-brand dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Menus
              <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Store Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Weedmaps</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
        <li><a href="pakablog.html">Pakablog</a></li>
        <li><a href="apparel.html">Apparel</a></li>
        <li><a href="cultivation.html">About</a></li>   
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
height:110px;
max-width: 1920px;
background-color: #222222;
}

.nav.nav-pills li a{
line-height: 3em;
padding: 0px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
color: white;
background-color: #222222;  
font-family: 'Wendy One', sans-serif;
font-size: 36px;
display: table-cell;
margin-top: -49px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-pills li a:hover{
  color: #4EB848;
  background-color: #222222;

}

.nav-pills>li.active>a, .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover, .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus{
  color: #4EB848;
  background-color: #222222;
}


@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none !important;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    display: block !important;
}
.navbar-header .collapse, .navbar-toggle {
    display:block !important;
}
.navbar-header {
    float:none;
}
}

#menuButton {
width:80px;
height: 80px;
align-content: center;
border-color: white;
}

 .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
 display: block;
 width: 55px;
 height: 5px;
 background-color: #cccccc;

}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
display: block;    
}

.dropdown-menu:hover{
display: block;
}

.navbar-brand.dropdown-toggle {
margin: 0px;
}

.dropdown {
position: absolute;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
margin-top: 45px;
margin-left: -20px;
padding: 10px;

}
```

Comment: why are you not able to change it with margins and padding.  Have you tried or is it just not an option for this project?

Comment: I have tried. You can see in the code right now I have margin: 0px and position: absolute.  I have tried margin-top with negative values as well to move it upwards.

Comment: Padding is also set to 0px and yet it still has a ton of padding shown by the blue box that isn't even centered.  I had this same problem on another project but I could move it with margins. I'm not sure why it wont let me.  I was hoping someone would see some dumb mistake I made.

Comment: V4 or V3 of bootstrap

Comment: Version 3. I was able to adjust the links position using line-height.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to align the dropdown menu with the rest of the links in the bootstrap navbar with line-height in .nav.nav-pills li a{}. I forgot I had used it earlier in the project to accomplish a general alignment of the links in the navbar. Further adjusting the value from 3em to 2.1em brought the dropdown menu to the position of the other links:

[image]

```
.nav.nav-pills li a{
**line-height: 2.1em;**
padding: 0px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
color: white;
background-color: #222222;  
font-family: 'Wendy One', sans-serif;
font-size: 36px;
display: table-cell;
margin-top: -49px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```